# Apiary JSONP response

Tags: apiary.io, apiary

Is there some way to use Apiary to respond appropriately to JSONP requests?

request looks like:

```
http://myserver.apiary-mock.com/api/v1/startup/dashboard?callback=jQuery20008137053514365107_1400036479208&user_id=1&_=1400036479210
```

and I need the request to take that jQuery string and wrap it around the response (normal response body shown as {...} below):

```
jQuery20008137053514365107_1400036479208({...})
```

So, if the normal request was:

```
http://myserver.apiary-mock.com/api/v1/startup/dashboard
```

And the normal response was:

```
{ "yes": true }
```

Then, adding a callback like:

```
http://myserver.apiary-mock.com/api/v1/startup/dashboard?callback=bob
```

Would make the response look like:

```
bob({ "yes": true })
```

Comment: hi, can you give use the call and the request that you want to perform?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... I  want to hit an Apiary route with that ?callback= on it and I want it to take the value of the callback parameter and wrap it around the response... I'll try and update my question to be more clear?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/M4Kt8/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apiary does not support this currently, [but *might* be working on it](http://support.apiary.io/forums/120125-general/suggestions/3264958-support-for-api-with-callbacks).